# Send latest props to mousemove event listener

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a click-and-drag component, which:

- creates a `moveListener` `onMouseDown`
- the `moveListener` dispatches an action which updates some of the component's props (`props.whichChange`)
- the `mouseUp` cleans up the above event listeners (and itself)

The problem is that the below results in the latest props being passed to the `'mousemove`' event listener function only once `onMouseDown`, whereas the lastest props are required every time a new `mousemove` event occurs.

How could I modify the below to achieve this?

```js
import React, { MouseEvent as ReactMouseEvent } from 'react';

export const MyComponent = props =>

    const generateMoveListener = args => {
        return (event: MouseEvent) => {
            dispatchAction(args);
        };
    };

    const onMouseDown = (event: ReactMouseEvent) => {
        inputsThatShouldntChange = doSomeCalcs(props.thatDontChange)
        const moveListener = generateMoveListener(inputsThatShouldntChange, props.whichChange);
        document.body.addEventListener('mousemove', moveListener);
        document.body.addEventListener('mouseup', function mouseUp() {
            document.body.removeEventListener('mousemove', moveListener);
            document.body.removeEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp);
        });
    };

    return (<ChildComponent onMouseDown={onMouseDown} />);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem was solved with `useRef` and `useEffect`:

```js
import React, { 
    MouseEvent as ReactMouseEvent,
    useEffect,
    useRef 
} from 'react';

export const MyComponent = props =>

    useEffect(() => {
        propsRef.current = props;
    }, [props]);

    const onMouseDown = (event: ReactMouseEvent) => {
        if (!propsRef.current) {
            return
        };

        const generateMoveListener = args => {
            return (event: MouseEvent) => {
                dispatchAction(args);
            };
        };

        inputsThatShouldntChange = doSomeCalcs(props.thatDontChange)
        
        const initialProps = props;
        const currentProps = propsRef.current

        const moveListener = generateMoveListener({
            initiapProps, 
            currentProps
        });

        document.body.addEventListener('mousemove', moveListener);

        document.body.addEventListener('mouseup', function mouseUp() {
            document.body.removeEventListener('mousemove', moveListener);
            document.body.removeEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp);
        });
    };

    return (<ChildComponent onMouseDown={onMouseDown} />);
};
```